# Looping by row across subset of columns

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame with column 1 being the gene and all other columns being gene expression data for that gene under different conditions. I want to go gene by gene and divide all the expression values by the median expression value for that gene. I have the medians in a data frame called s.med.df.

I’m trying to direct R to divide all the expression columns (2:n) but not the first column by the median value for each gene. I'm new to R, but the script I have so far is as follows:

```
Con1 <- c(5088.77, 274.62, 251.97, 122.21)
Con2 <- c(4382.59, 288.55, 208.12, 171.93)
Con3 <- c(4732.81, 417.43, 305.58, 132.93)
Solid.df <- data.frame(Gene = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Con1=Con1, Con2=Con2, Con3=Con3)

Gene    Con1     Con2     Con3
A       5088.77  4382.59  4732.81
B       274.62   288.55   417.43
C       251.97   208.12   305.58
D       122.21   171.93   132.93

n <- ncol(Solid.df)
genes = levels(s.med.df$Gene)
Solid.mt.df = Solid.df
for (i in 1:length(genes)) {
  gene = genes[i]
  Solid.mt.df[2:n][Solid.mt.df$Gene == gene] = Solid.mt.df[2:n][Solid.mt.df$Gene == gene] / s.med.df$Medians[i]
  print(gene)
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: showing your data would help to reproduce the problem. you might also want to use one of the `apply` functions to speed up the calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by direct divide. Change `s.med.df` to a vector. See the following example.

```
d1 <- data.frame(ge=c("A", "B", "C"), e1=1:3, e2=7:9,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
m1 <- data.frame(md=4:6, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

d1[,2:3]/unlist(m1)
#     e1   e2
# 1 0.25 1.75
# 2 0.40 1.60
# 3 0.50 1.50
```

Can also bind the gene names with the results.

```
cbind(d1[,1], d1[,2:3]/unlist(m1))
```

Comment: Thanks! this was much simpler than what I was trying to do, but it worked great! It ended up being a single line:

`Solid.mt.df[,-1] <- Solid.mt.df[,-1] / s.med.df$Medians`

Answer (score 0):

For anything to do with applying a function over columns or rows, you're looking for apply:

```
median_centered <- t(apply(genes[,2:length(genes)], 1, function(x) x / median(x)))
genes2 <- cbind(genes[,1], median_centered)
```

This takes the data frame except for the first column, iterates over the 1st axis (rows), and applies x / median(x) to those rows.  Since R broadcasts scalar operations to vectors, you'll get the desired result, but it will be transposed, so calling t() on it turns it back into the original format.  Then we can cbind it back with the gene names.

Answer (score 0):

like @VenYao pointed out, you can use direct division if you turn your medians into a vector. It would be helpful to show what structure is your s.med.df file.

This can be achieved using `data.table` pretty easily:

`cbind` your dataframes into a data.table:

```
library(data.table)
combined <- data.table(cbind(Solid.df, s.med.df))
combined[, med.con1 := Con1/median]  
# assume median is the column in s.med.df that stores median values. 
# then you can repeat that for all three conditions:
combined[, med.con2 := Con2/median] 
combined[, med.con2 := Con2/median]
```